Single employer 401k excess contribution
I maxed out my pre-tax 401(k) earlier this year. I had already used up my entire employer match, so the remaining money flowing into the account was after-tax. When I looked at my most recent statement, I noticed that my YTD total contributions are now $72k. Since I am under 50 years old, my limit for this year is $69k. Apparently there was no automatic cutoff of contributions above the limit, so now my 401(k) holds $3k that it shouldn't.
Schwab indicates that they'll return the money to me by April 15 of next year, but that they can't do anything in the meantime. (In case anyone is curious, Schwab has my correct DOB in their system: they don't think I'm over 50). All of the other posts I've seen about excess contributions relate to folks who had multiple 401(k)s over the course of a year, but I've only had this one. Do I have any options other than waiting 11 months for my money back?

This is money you were going to set aside anyway. It's not enough that setting it aside differently will make a huge difference. What's the rush?

Why are they waiting for April? Did you submit the request?

That question is better answered by Schwab whom I assume is your 401K custodian.  It seems like they did.  Your option is to wait patiently for the mistake you made, and not make it in the future.
First off, perspective.  We are talking about 3K here, in a year where you are investing 69K in your retirement.  It's likely that Schwab will invest the money anyway, so what is really lost?
Owning and running a business is not easy, even a one-man shop.  I needed my wife's help to do so, and I was a one-man shop with a single client.  We also hired an accountant and outsourced our payroll.  Still, we made mistakes as well.
You cannot really blame Schwab as very few people hit that upper limit as few have generous matches that extend so far beyond the individual contribution limit.  It's a condition that their software was not coded to handle.   
Take some deep breaths, and learn from this.

The OP mentions “single employer” to emphasize that they were employed by only one company when all this happened -most people who end up over-contributing to a 401K work for multiple companies in a year and so the separate companies have no idea when the individual is about to hit the limit. They’re not talking about a Solo 401K so your remarks about small businesses don’t seem to be relevant here.

It’s 2024. 401Ks have existed for over 40 years at this point. Brokerages get paid very well to run plans, and they really ought to be able to handle basic functions like enforcing well-known contribution limits.

@nobody Ought to, and actually do are two very different things.  My previous employer used "Empower" and they couldn't even handle catch up contributions properly.

"few have generous matches" -- hitting the $69k limit does not require a large match. OP mentions making employee after-tax contributions, which can push total contributions to the limit even with little or no employer match. (Such after-tax contributions can be useful for a backdoor Roth.) Also, I can blame Schwab in that the total contribution limit (currently $69k) is not obscure but is fundamental to the 401k construct.
